# In Ansible, how to specify current date plus 2 year in epoch?

Tags: ansible, epoch

I am working on writing a playbook to add a large number of users each semester for my college. I would like to set up these accounts to expire automatically two years after the playbook is run. I know I can specify expiration in epoch...but how do I look up the epoch for a future date in the midst of a playbook run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let’s say your target date is two years from tomorrow. Then you can use most any system’s `date` command to get its epoch value:

```
date -d '2015-09-22 + 2 years' '+%s'
```

Then in Ansible, you can *register* that date you’re targeting with something like (not tested):

```
- name: register end of semester expiry
  command: date -d '2015-09-22 + 2 years' '+%s'
  register: expiry_r

- name: create user accts with expiry
  user: ... expires={{expiry_r.stdout}}
```

Comment: You can use "now", so I'd lean toward: "date -d 'now + 2 years' '+%s'"

Comment: Or probably just `lookup('pipe','date -d "now + 2 years" "+%s"')`

It only works on Linux with this exact syntax though